# Converting 4e Forgotten Realms setting to 3.5e or Pathfinder

Tags: dnd-4e, dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e, conversion, campaign-settings

I'm trying to use the 4th edition Forgotten Realms campaign setting in either Pathfinder or D&D 3.5, which I use, as the idea for the Spellplague is awesome. Can someone help me convert this from 4e to 3.5e or, preferably, Pathfinder?

I want to convert the new races, feats, items, classes, and if possible, the utility actions into combat maneuvers. Also, a few of my players want to play spellscarred characters, so the feats need to be there.

Comment: As posed this is asking for a full conversion, which is a pretty significant task, likely worthy of a book, not an SE question. If you have specific bits you get stuck on we can help with that, but asking for the full conversion is out of scope here.